# Codeception aspectmock can't mock object in Yii2

Tags: codeception

I have read the guide and follow to install and set up AspectMock to Yii2 basic. Everything is fine, but it seem to be not actually work, the object is not mocked. I think the issue may be derived from path configuration, but I didn't find the solution. This is my code:

At bootstrap file

```
# tests/codeception/_bootstrap.php
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'test');

defined('YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL') or define('YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL', parse_url(\Codeception\Configuration::config()['config']['test_entry_url'], PHP_URL_PATH));
defined('YII_TEST_ENTRY_FILE') or define('YII_TEST_ENTRY_FILE', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/web/index-test.php');

$kernel = \AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'debug' => true,
    'includePaths' => [__DIR__.'/../../'],
]);
$kernel->loadFile(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = YII_TEST_ENTRY_FILE;
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = YII_TEST_ENTRY_URL;
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = parse_url(\Codeception\Configuration::config()['config']['test_entry_url'], PHP_URL_HOST);
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] =  parse_url(\Codeception\Configuration::config()['config']['test_entry_url'], PHP_URL_PORT) ?: '80';

Yii::setAlias('@tests', dirname(__DIR__));
```

In test file

```
# test/codeception/models/UserTest.php
<?php
namespace tests\codeception\unit\models;

use yii\codeception\TestCase;
use app\models\User;
use AspectMock\Test as test;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        test::clean(); 
    }
        public function testUserObject()
    {
        $user = test::double(User::className(), [
            'getId' => '5'
        ]);
        $user->getId();
        $user->verifyInvoked('getId');
    }
}
```

This is result

> [Exception] Called app\models\User->getId, but this is a proxy for a
>   class definition. Probably you was trying to access instance method.
>   Construct an instance from this class

Does I make wrong some thing? Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used AspectMock, but by looking at https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock I think that you mocked the wrong thing.

`test::double('className')` mocks static methods, 
to mock the object you have to pass the instance of the class: https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock#beautifully-simple

`$user = test::double(new User, ['getName' => 'davert']);`

If you only want to mock objects, [Codeception\Util\Stub](http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Stub) provides enough functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to actually instantiate the mock. Try this instead:

```
<?php
public function testUserObject()
{
    $user = test::double(User::className(), [
        'getId' => '5'
    ]);
    $user-make();
    $user->getId();
    $user->verifyInvoked('getId');
}
```